# what field type to use for model field in form in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need to make a model field read only in my form.  I do this with the following:

```
class ActivityEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    activity = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
    duration = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerActivity
        fields = ('activity', 'duration',)
```

Activity is an actual model foreign key field to the CustomerActivity model.

This currently displays the Activity Id number.  I want it to print the name of the activity.

What field type do I use or how can I show the name instead of the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that the `readonly` attribute is not safe to prevent changes. Any nitwit can change the html code nowadays with inspect element etc. built into any browser. For security reasons it's better to exclude the field from the form and present the data in another way, or to have a server-side check to prevent people from changing data.

That's also a good way to solve your question. As an instance of a `ModelForm`, your form has an `instance` attribute which holds the actual data related to the object, given that this data exists. Instead of going through an unused form field, use the data form the instance as-is:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly">{% firstof form.instance.activity.name "<default>" %}</input>
```